# vertical navigation bar?

Tags: c#

Sorry for this question, but I've been Googling "C# vertical menu bar" for a while, and I can't find one that looks something like this:
[image]

No, I'm not making a survey locker, but that's the only image I could find of what I'm looking for.

Could anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Looks like vertical tabs. WinForms or WPF?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

You can creat custom User Control that Inherit from Tab Control.

For Windows Forms, Follow Below Steps:

1. Right Click Project -> Add New Item -> User Control(C#)
2. Inherit from TabControl and write below code in Default Constructor
   3 Override OnPaint Method to manually Design Tab Control
3. Save it
4. Add it to your Form from toolbox.
5. Set Dock Property to Fill and Alignment Property to Left of Control
6. Add more Tabs

Hope this Helps!

```
    class CustomControl : TabControl
    {
         public CustomControl()
         {
          SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint  , true);
          SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer , true);
          SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
          SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);

          DoubleBuffered = true;
          SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
          ItemSize = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 120);

         }


        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
         var B = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
         var G = (Graphics)Graphics.FromImage(B);
         G.Clear(Color.Gainsboro);

          for (int i = 0; i < TabCount -1; i++)
          {
            var TabRectangle = (Rectangle)GetTabRect(i);

            if (i == SelectedIndex)
            {
                G.FillRectangle(Brushes.Navy, TabRectangle);
            }
            else
            {

                G.FillRectangle(Brushes.BlueViolet, TabRectangle);


            }
            G.DrawString(TabPages[i].Text, Font, Brushes.White, TabRectangle, new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center });
            TabPages[i].Font = new Font(TabPages[i].Font, FontStyle.Strikeout);

        }

        e.Graphics.DrawImage((Image)B.Clone(),0,0);
        G.Dispose();
        B.Dispose();

        base.OnPaint(e);

       }
```

[image]

[image]

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming WPF, just plop a menu thats taller than its wider and add menu items

Comment: I'm using WinForms, now WPF.

Comment: Then use vertical tabs like p.s.w.g. said